# Adjusting sound of certain program in Windows using command-line?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Is this possible? I saw NirCmd but it can adjust only master sound, is there any way to adjust sound for certain program only, same as in Mixer...

Answer (score 0):

In Case you are still looking, I wrote a small tool in C#, utilizing the Windows Core Audio API, with [this library here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control) (CoreAudio2). You can find the Command Line Tool [here](http://thisismeta.at/media/VolumeSetter.zip)

Here's how you use it. You have three options, list (-l), info (-i) and set (-s):

With list, you have the following output: `id: <a active, i inactive> program name - window title.`

```
VolumeSetter.exe -l
0: <i> wmplayer -
1: <i> wmplayer -
2: <i> Steam - Steam
3: <a> chrome - What are Continents? - YouTube - Google Chrome
4: <i> FlashPlayerPlugin_13_0_0_214 -
5: <i> plugin-container -
6: <i> Idle -
7: <i> firefox - New Tab - Mozilla Firefox

VolumeSetter.exe -i 3
Id: 3
Application: chrome
Window Title: What are Continents? - YouTube - Google Chrome
Active: True
Volume: 0,5
Mute: False

VolumeSetter.exe -s 3 100
Volume of chrome - What are Continents? - YouTube - Google Chrome set to 100
```